# Allocating memory with Malloc in C (Own OS)

Tags: c, operating-system, kernel

Me and my colleague are working on our own operating system. We wanted to implement malloc and paging. I then found this malloc definition on the internet:

```c
void* malloce(uint32_t size);
 void* mem = (void*)0x100000;
 for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
     memcpy(mem + i, mem, 1);
 }
return mem;
```

I've tried it and it works, but I don't think so little code is enough

I tried this in the Kernel:

```c
    int* numbers = malloce(sizeof(int) * 10);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        numbers[i] = i;
    }
    //print array of numbers
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        printf("%d\n", numbers[i]);
    }
```

(Extra called "malloce")

It worked and I was able to write the numbers 0-9 into the array and print them afterwards

[image]

Then I did the same again but did malloc(0).

```c
 int* numbers = malloce(0);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        numbers[i] = i;
    }
    //print array of numbers
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        printf("%d\n", numbers[i]);
    }
```

And for some reason it still worked. I'm confused

Can somebody help?

Thanks :)

Comment: Why use different type for `uint32_t size` and `int i`?  I'd expect the same and suggest they both use `size_t`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set up any memory protection for allocated memory blocks, you can write wherever in RAM. Malloc doesn't guarantee that you can only write to the memory allocated (by itself, without OS support), it just checks a whether the given size of memory is available in its pool (although this pool is OS managed as well).

If this `malloce` implementation doesn't check for 0 size (it appears it doesn't), than you can do whatever you want with the memory address it returns.